# Unparseable date in SAML Authentication for Zimbra Collaboration Open Source

Tags: single-sign-on, simplesamlphp, zimbra

I have set up Zimbra Collaboration Open Source as service provider (SP) and SimpleSAMLphp as Identity Provider (IdP). I have downloaded Network Edition, extract the store rpm, grab samlextn.jar and follow the instructions to configure SAML.

Zimbra server environment:

```
[zimbra@devzimbra ~]$ zmcontrol -v
Release 7.2.0_GA_2669.RHEL6_64_20120410002025 CentOS6_64 FOSS edition.
[zimbra@devzimbra ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

After successfully authenticate in IdP and SAML response is sent to http://devzimbra/service/extension/samlreceiver, I'm getting this error in browser:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /service/extension/samlreceiver. Reason:

    Unparseable date: "2018-12-13T09:48:09Z"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a problem with saml extension for Zimbra (version 7.2). I've tested with current Zimbra (version 8.8.10) and found no problem parsing date from the same IdP server.